# (R) How to include arguments when passing a function?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Sorry for the jumbled title. I'm not sure the right wording for this.

I have the situation below. `SelfLearning()` has the `method` argument, which is a function. I want `method=LibLinear` and I'd like to include an argument to `LibLinear` itself, namely the argument `type=2`. I'm not sure how to do that.

How do I get something like B to work?

```
library(RSSL)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# dummy dataset
df <- generate2ClassGaussian(200, d=2, var = 0.2, expected=TRUE)

# A
# this works, but without LibLinear(type=2)
g_self <- SelfLearning(Class~.,df,
                       method = NearestMeanClassifier,
                       prior=matrix(0.5,2))

# B
# trying to pass method=LibLinear(type=2) does not work
g_self <- SelfLearning(Class~.,df,
                       method = LiblineaR(type=2), # <-- how do I fix this?
                       prior=matrix(0.5,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments for the method can be passed as additional arguments into the function itself. In your case, you can write:

```
g_self <- SelfLearning(Class~.,df,
                       method = LiblineaR,
                       prior=matrix(0.5,2),type=2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get the error "Error in SelfLearning(Class ~ ., df[, 1:2], method = LiblineaR, prior = matrix(0.5, :  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'", but I think that's a deepr problem with SelfLearning and LiblineaR.